# Highlighting functions in jupiter lab

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I updated my computer, installed a new python and all the necessary libraries, all new versions. I go to jupiter lab, as a result I see something strange with the backlight.

Keywords, variable values, functions or classes from libraries are highlighted. But, standard functions or, for example, the data type is not highlighted, this can be clearly seen in the screenshot.

[image: example]

I would be very grateful if someone knows what the problem may be, and how can I fix it myself in the settings?

I tried reinstalling jupyterlab, python, installing python and other libraries manually. Nothing helped